# Why can't System.Array be a type constraint?

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, compiler-errors, generic-constraints

I'm working on a small project with a few different types of arrays (e.g. `double[]`, `float[]`, `int[]`. For verification / testing / sanity purposes, I'm printing out some of these arrays to the console as I go along. So I have multiple functions that look like these below (simplified for this example - assume I'm only dealing with single-dimension arrays):

```
void Print(float[] a) // prints an array of floats
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(a[i]);
    }
}

void Print(double[] a) // prints an array of doubles
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(a[i]);
    }
}
```

I, in my infinite wisdom, thought I could reduce some of the code duplication by simply creating a generic version of these functions. So I tried this:

```
void Print<T>(T t) where T : Array
{
    for (int i = 0; i < t.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(t.GetValue(i));
    }
}
```

Intellisense isn't complaining, but the compiler fails with a very interesting error:

> `Constraint cannot be special class 'System.Array'`

I've looked for an explanation (similar to `Object` or sealed classes, but haven't found much, besides a mention [on msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56b2hk61.aspx). Can anyone explain to me *why* this is the case? Why can't I specify a type constraint of `System.Array`?

p.s.: While typing this out, I realized that I can accomplish what I originally wanted more easily, with a simple function like this:

```
void Print(System.Array a)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(a.GetValue(i));
    }
}
```

Is this why there's a special rule for arrays in the compiler?

Comment: So no actual answer so far.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The appropriate syntax to do what you want is this:

```
void Print<T>(T[] array)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write(array[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes sense, but I'm still curious _why_ I can't have a base class type constraint of `Array`...

Comment: Also, out of curiosity, is that different from using a parameter of type `Array`? Is there some boxing going on if I use `Array`?

Comment: @vlad There's no boxing since arrays are reference types, not value types, although you are boxing the objects you get out of it unlike with a typed array.  It's also not the same since an `Array` could also be a 2, 3, or N dimentional array, or an array that's not 0 indexed.

Comment: Also makes sense. Just to be clear, you're saying that what I tried to write is simply not allowed by the compiler, because the correct syntax is what you posted? That is, everything that can be done with `where T : Array` can be done in the parameter list?

Comment: @vlad You should either be using this syntax or just passing an array in a non-generic method, in the event that you do not know the dimension of the array being passed in or are dealing with a 1 (or any non-zero) indexed array.

Comment: what if you wanted your constraints to be say  double[] or double[,]

Comment: @mike01010 Then you don't use generics and you create two overloads.

Answer (score -1):

If taken the question literally, it would be useless to have an `Array` constraint. It's the same as it's useless to have a `ValueType` constraint, as it actually doesn't check whether you use a value type as a generic argument, but whether the type you are passing is assignable to `ValueType`.
So you can pass even `Array` as the generic argument and it's OK.

What is actually useful is to have an *array* contraint allowing any type that derives from `Array`, but not `Array` itself:

```
void Print<TArr>(TArr t) where TArr : array //or [*] or other fancy syntax
```

Where `T` can be `[]`, `[,]`, `[,,]`, `[,,,]`, and so on. The only over non-generic `Array` parameter is that we know the element type of the array.

Another way to solve this is to create a custom `Array<T>` class with implicit operator overloads of `T[]`, `T[,]`, `T[,,]` etc.

Edit:
There is no way to achieve this even in CIL (currently), because `int[,]` and `Array` don't differ in any interfaces or constructors. We need `where T : Array but not Array itself` contraint.

Comment: It wouldn't be quite useless.  Were it not for the prohibition, one could write a `CopyAndReverseArraySegment<T>(T dest, T source, int start, int length) where T:System.Array` and have it accept invocations where either or both of the source or destination was `System.Array`, but still reject invocations where `source` and `dest` were incompatible array types.  As it is, I don't believe there is a way to allow `System.Array` as a particular type for one of the parameters without having any derivative of that type also be deemed acceptable.