# Deducing if a generic is an array type at compile time

Tags: c#, arrays

As documented upstream, one cannot use 'array' as base constraints:

> [[...]Some types are disallowed as a base class constraint: Object, Array,
> and ValueType.[...]](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint)

However there seems to be minimal type inference for array as seen at:

- [C# generic constraint: Array of Structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379573/c-sharp-generic-constraint-array-of-structs)
- [Why can't System.Array be a type constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795017/why-cant-system-array-be-a-type-constraint)

My goal is to extend the original SO post, to handle also array types:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68949729/136285

So my naive attempt is as follow:

```
public class JsonDictionary
{
    public static readonly Key<int> Int = new Key<int> { Name = "INT" };
    public static readonly Key<int[]> Int3 = new Key<int[]> { Name = "INT3" };
    
    IDictionary<string, object> _data;
    public JsonDictionary()
    {
        _data = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    }
    public void Set<T>(Key<T> key, T obj)
    {
        if (obj is int[] objArray) // FIXME: runtime check
        {
            if (objArray.Length != 3)
                throw new FormatException("Illegal INT3");
        }
        _data[key.Name] = obj;
    }
    public T Get<T>(Key<T> key)
    {
        return (T)_data[key.Name];
    }
    public class Key<T>
    {
        public string Name { get; init; }
    }
}
```

Usage is simply:

```
var d = new JsonDictionary();
d.Set(JsonDictionary.Int, 42);
var i = d.Get(JsonDictionary.Int);
d.Set(JsonDictionary.Int3, new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
var i3 = d.Get(JsonDictionary.Int3);
Assert.Throws<FormatException>(() => d.Set(JsonDictionary.Int3, new int[] { 1, 2 }));
```

Notice how I used a runtime check (`obj is int[] objArray`) because I could not use some kind of constraint for 'array'.

Is there a way to rewrite the above so that I can have two different `Set` functions, one for `T` and one for `T[]`. Otherwise I would need to handle all possible types with an ugly if/else:

```
        if (obj is int[] objArray)
        {
            if (objArray.Length != 3)
                throw new FormatException("Illegal INT3");
        }
        else if (obj is ushort[] objArray)
        {
            if (objArray.Length != 3)
                throw new FormatException("Illegal USHORT3");
        }
        else if (obj is double[] objArray)
        {
            if (objArray.Length != 3)
                throw new FormatException("Illegal DOUBLE3");
        }
        [...]
```

Comment: For clarification: are you asking how to create a generic method with a constraint on the input being an array, or are you asking how to determine if a variable holds an array?

Comment: Consider alternative approach where you create custom type to represent your constraints. _Make illegal represenation impossible_

Comment: @Llama: IMHO the latter: "... because I could not use some kind of constraint for 'array'." I think your deleted answer is correct

Comment: what about `where T: IEnumerable<whatever>`?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Being careful with `string` (or should I say `IEnumerable<char>`) of course :)

Comment: @Llama I agree, however as OP is asking for a **generic** function, so  `string` should be valid as well. Otherweise he shouldn't use generics in the first place.

Comment: @HimBromBeere I know, but I just wanted to point it out in case OP decides to go that route and gets surprised by `string` being treated as an `IEnumerable<char>`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere based on `d.Set(JsonDictionary.Int, 42);` it seems that not only arrays are allowed.

Comment: "Is there a way to rewrite the above so that I can have two different `Set` functions, one for `T` and one for `T[]`" I'm pretty sure overload resolution will pick the array overload if you pass an array type, so you should be able to just write another overload like `public void Set<T>(Key<T[]> key, T[] obj)`. ([this is also the answer to one of your linked posts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14795031/5133585)) What's preventing you from doing that?

Comment: please add some information about which types the constraint should actually match. What about `string[]` for example? Would `List<int>` be okay also? Or `DateTime[]`? Ask youself what those types have in common.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check if it's an `Array`:

```cs
if (obj is Array arr && arr.Length != 3)
{
    throw new FormatException("Illegal array. Expected length 3.");
}
```

Comment: that's pretty much the same OP already has, isn't it?

Comment: @HimBromBeere Yes, but without them having to explicitly implement every possible array type under the sun.

Comment: but it has the same problem you mentioned within the comments - e.g. for strings.

Comment: @HimBromBeere That's not what I can see in my testing. `string` isn't derived from `Array`: [example](https://rextester.com/WIDBQ17809).

Comment: what about `new string[3]`. It's not clear to me if or igf not is a valid array for OP.

Comment: @HimBromBeere That would definitely be an array.

Comment: from my understanding - see my answer - OP not only needs an array-like constraint but also a **numeric** one, which is impossible.

Comment: @HimBromBeere That wasn't my understanding, but you may well be right.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you shouldn't use generics here at all. There's absolutely nothing common between an `int[]` and a `double[]`, as there is no constraint for numbers - nor for arrays.

You *could* in some way workaround your problem with a constraint for `IEnumerable`, but that would also fit `int[]`, but also a `List<MyClass>`.

So even **if** there was a constraint for arrays, there's no constraint for the array-**type**.

So after all you should have different method for different types:

```
Set(int i) => ...
Set(int[] arr) => ...
Set(double d) => ...
Set(double[]) => ...
```

Comment: Having a different method seems like the better option overall, assuming OP won't ever pass an `object` and expect the method to "just handle it".

Comment: I fail to understand the first sentence `It seems like you shouldn't use generics here at all.`  Can you include a minimal code sample on how you would have done the above ?

Comment: @malat just one method per type: one for `int`, one for `int[]`, one for `double`, one for `double[]` and so forth.

Comment: OK, thanks for the clarification now I understand. Anyway the above is based on previous post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2178769/136285. I still believe that your `Set` are kindda duplicate and I assumed Generic would be a good fit.

Comment: @malat to reduce the duplication, you may have a private method that does all the common logic.