# C# generic constraint: interface or array of interface

Tags: c#, generics, interface

I am trying to understand how to use constraints in my use case. Here is pseudo code:

```cs
public interface IEmployee
{
    string Name { get; }
    int Id { get; }
}

public class Processor<T> where T : IEmployee
{
    public T Process()
    {
      ...
    }
}
```

Now I have a new use case where I can return an array of `IEmployee`, as far as I understand there is no way to specify this as constraints:

- [C# generic constraint: Array of Structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20379573/c-sharp-generic-constraint-array-of-structs)
- [Why can't System.Array be a type constraint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795017/why-cant-system-array-be-a-type-constraint)

A quick fix would be to simply comment out the original generic constraints and have:

```cs
public class Processor<T> /*where T : IEmployee */
```

I was wondering if there was any other alternative solution to require the programmer to pass in a proper type (implementation of my interface) in the case of IEmployee[] array type.

---

Update. In the end both syntax should compile:

```cs
public record Employee(string Name, int Id) : IEmployee;
public class Processor1 : Processor<Employee> {...}
public class Processor2 : Processor<Employee[]> {...}
```

---

Update2: My question is **not** about re-writing an existing framework or changing API. I simply need to express a constraint so that I get a compile time failure when programmer does not return the proper type.

How can I express such a compile time constraint ?

Comment: ^^ => https://dotnetfiddle.net/R3zu5l ? I don't get it. You can constrain the _class_ to `T:IEmployee` _and_ have methods return `T[]` .... or take in a `T[]` as argument for that matter.

Comment: added an update section on what I want to have in the end

Comment: How would you _actually_ implement a generic method/class that can handle both of those?

Comment: Why not just have one `T Process()` and one `T[] ProcessMany()` ?

Comment: @fildor that's precisely my point here I do not want to change the entire framework

Comment: There's no "simply" in what you ask. A type parameter must satisfy *all* type constraints. Even your own code wouldn't be able to work without casting to either `Employee` or `Employee[]` first.

Comment: If you don't want to modify the Processor class, use `Employee[]` only and pass an array with a single item if you only want to process one item

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public record Employee(string Name, int Id) : IEmployee;
public class Processor1 : Processor<Employee> {...}
public class Processor2 : Processor<Employee[]> {...}
```

There is no way to make both of these work while keeping the restriction. An item is not the same thing as a collection of said items.

There are a few possible alternatives:

1. Change the method signature to `T[] Process()`. The singular employee case can be handled by creating an array with one employee.
2. Change the restriction to `where T : IEnumerable<IEmployee>`. This will make `class Processor2 : Processor<Employee[]>` work just fine. You need to restrict the type to a read-only collection interface to prevent someone trying to add some other employee-type to the array.
3. Create a different class for the "return many" scenario. There is a chance that the "return array"-use case is more different than you think, and using different classes to handle different use cases might be appropriate.

It is difficult to tell what option is most appropriate from the given context.

Comment: Thanks for `where T : IEnumerable<IEmployee>` hint !